# VueJS / Jest - Testing if an imported function is called from a component's method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

I have a VueJS 2 component that looks something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="onFavorite">
      Add to favorites
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { trackFavorite } from "@/utils/analytics";

export default {
  name: "FavoriteButton",
  methods: {
    onFavorite() {
      trackFavorite("click", "favorite");
      [ ... ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to write a Jest test that checks that when `onFavorite` is run `trackFavorite` is called. Tried something like this:

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import FavoriteButton from '../FavoriteButton'

describe("FavoriteButton", () => {
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(FavoriteButton)
  })

  describe('.onFavorite', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper.vm.trackFavorite = jest.fn()
      wrapper.vm.onFavorite()
    })

    it('calls trackFavorite', () => {
      expect(wrapper.vm.trackFavorite).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
  })
})
```

But it doesn't work as `trackFavorite` is not replaced by the Jest mock function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `jest.mock()` at the top of the test file to mock the entire import (including its methods).
2. `require()` the file within the test to access the mock.
3. With the mock reference, verify the mocked `trackFavorite` method is called.

```js
// FavoriteButton.spec.js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import FavoriteButton from '@/components/FavoriteButton.vue'

jest.mock('@/utils/analytics') 1️⃣

describe('FavoriteButton.vue', () => {
  it('calls trackFavorite on button click', async () => {
    const analytics = require('@/utils/analytics') 2️⃣
    const wrapper = shallowMount(FavoriteButton)
    await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
    expect(analytics.trackFavorite).toHaveBeenCalled() 3️⃣
  })
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-mock-imported-function-jest?file=tests/unit/FavoriteButton.spec.ts)

Comment: Many thanks. As an extra caution for whoever happens upon this, the `jest.mock` line should be placed outside of any describe / it block.